# Can a PostgreSQL failover work on storage shared by a 32-bit and 64-bit host?

Tags: postgresql

I've got two PostgreSQL 9.2.4 servers running on 32-bit Suse.
Failover is configured using a shared storage device.
I'd like to upgrade to 64-bit Ubuntu machines using PostgreSQL's streaming replication while keeping the database service available.  To do that would mean temporarily having failover between a 32-bit and 64-bit system.

I've read a lot of documentation for PostgreSQL & PostgreSQL replication.
It's clear that PostgreSQL doesn't handle streaming replication between 32 & 64 bit systems.  It's not as clear if it can handle shared storage between 32 & 64 bit systems.  I'm pessimistic, but wanted to check.

Comment: Looks like no: http://blog.xk72.com/post/16304648626/installing-32-bit-postgresql-on-64-bit-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can - with the caveat that you must use a 32-bit PostgreSQL build on your 64-bit system, it must be the same major release (e.g. both 9.2 or both 9.3) and it must be compiled with the same settings for `integer_datetimes` etc.

Modern Debian/Ubuntu, like all 64-bit Red Hat variants, supports a multi-arch install where 32-bit and 64-bit binaries can live side by side. So you should be able to simply `apt-get install` the 32-bit PostgreSQL on your 64-bit system.

That said, I *strongly* suggest relying on streaming replication instead. Shared-storage failover is *very risky* - if you have any problems with fencing access and STONITH, you will get *extremely severe data corruption*. It also protects against fewer classes of problems.

Comment: I agree that streaming replication is the way to go.  This setup was inherited from a previous developer & has been migrated from shared storage to streaming replication.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's even possible that 32-bit Suse's version of PostgreSQL and 32-bit Ubuntu's aren't compatible. Not likely, but it depends on what options they chose during compilation.

So - no.

If you really want to have complete availability you'll need to look at one of the trigger-based replication systems (slony / londiste / bucardo). These can replicate between different installations of PostgreSQL regardless of on-disk format.

Of course, this means having two sets of data.

It does allow you for an uninterrupted upgrade though, so you can consider switching to the latest 9.3 at the same time.